# Render Email with batch

Tags: apex, batch, scheduled-apex

I am working on a batch class to send summarized email to the all  owner regarding the standard obj modified recently.

```
 global class ContactStatus implements Database.Batchable<sObject>{


        global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC)
        {
            String query = 'SELECT Id, Name,Account.Ownerid,Account.owner.email, Account.Description, CreatedBy.Name FROM Contact where lastmodifieddate=today';
            return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
        }

        global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Contact> scope)
        {
            for ( Contact a : scope)
            {

             //trying the logic here to send an email consist of all contact updated to account owner email ids 
            }

        }  
        global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC)
        {


        }
    }
```

Comment: This is not a question. What are you trying to achieve? What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: You should consider a `Visualforce Email Template` and `Workfow Email Alert` on the `Account` object for this functionality.

Comment: Sure it can if you are clever. That's the point of a **Visualforce** template...you can pull in child records. Your batch would just have to update some checkbox to force the WFR to fire.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a template to get you started (if you choose to go the Apex code way):

```
public class YourClass implements
        Database.Batchable<SObject>, 
        Database.Stateful,
        Schedulable {

    private Map<String, Set<String>> messages = new Map<String, Set<String>>();

    public void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {
        Database.executeBatch(new YourClass());
    }

    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
        // Query
    }

    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<Contacts> scope) {
        // Collect data to send in email and store in messages e.g.:
        for (Contact c : scope) {
            Set<String> s = messages.get(c.Account.Owner.Email);
            if (s == null) {
                s = new Set<String>();
                messages.put(c.Account.Owner.Email, s);
            }
            s.add(c.Name);
        }
    }

    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
        // Send email using data from messages array
    }
}
```

Your can schedule this to run at say 2am every night.

Google to get more detail.

Comment: @cloudy-ritesh Not to sure what you mean; I've modified the code to what I think will work.

Comment: Cheers ! It worked .

Answer (score 2):

I will pull my comments here into an answer. I suggest this general path:

- Create a `Visualforce Email Template` on `Account`.

  - Have this template pull in relevant child `Contact` information.
- Create a checkbox field on `Account` called something like `Send_Contacts_Modified_Today__c`.
- Create a `Workflow Rule` to send the emails.

  - The criteria would simply look for the checkbox field changed to true.
  - The first action would be an `Email Alert` to send out this template.
  - The second action would be a field update to set the checkbox back to false.
- Write a batch to set this checkbox.

  ```
  public Database.queryLocator start(BatchableContext context)
  {
      return Database.getQueryLocator([SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Id IN (
          SELECT AccountId FROM Contact WHERE LastModifiedDate = TODAY
      )]);
  }
  public void execute(Database.BatchableContext context, List<Account> records)
  {
      for (Account record : records)
          record.Send_Contacts_Modified_Today__c = true;
      update records;
  }
  public void finish(Database.BatchableContext context) { }
  ```